# wrong value at pow function in for loop

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to make an IP calculator on Arduino, but in this part Im getting a wrong result, i'm expecting  a 128, but it returns 127, I think the problem is in the pow function(2,i) because if I hardcode the pow with a (2,7) I get the 128. this is the code

```
result=0;
binNumber="10110100"; //I this bin number in another function
firstchar= binNumber.substring(0, 1); //extract the first char
c0="0000000"; 
fullNumber= firstchar + c0;
for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){
  x = String (fullNumber[7-i]);
  xint= x.toInt();
  result= result + xint * pow(2,i);
}
lcd.print(result);
```

Comment: What if instead you use:  result = String.toInt("B" + binNumber);

Comment: @Duston your C compiler would complain that you were trying to use C++.

Comment: Maybe, but it's perfectly valid in the Arduino dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `pow(2,i)`. Use `1<<i`. By using bit shifts, you will avoid possible floating point errors.